# Passing the callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, callback

I have a Modelmenu that is nested in the parent component, it implements the function of opening a modal window by click. Also in this parent component there is a child component to which you need to bind the function of opening a modal window by one more element. I can do this if all the logic is in the parent component, but this is a bad practice, since I will have to duplicate the code on each page in this way. How can I do this? I'm sorry, I'm quite new, I can't understand the callback.

**Parent:**

```
 const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const handleCallback = (handleOpen: any) => {

    }
    return (
        <>
            <ModalMenu parentCallback={handleCallback}/>
            <Slider handleCallback={handleCallback}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Modal:**

```
export const ModalMenu: FC = (props) => {

    const [play, setPlay] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const handleOpen = () => {
        props.parentCallback(setPlay(!play))
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setPlay(false)
        setPlay(!play)
    };

    return
}
```

**Child:**

```
export const Slider: FC= (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <Image nClick={props.handleCallback}/>
        </>
```

Comment: "*I will have to duplicate the code on each page in this way.*" - that's when you introduce a custom hook for this

Comment: @Bergi Could you write me how to do it? Preferably in a detailed answer

Comment: Just put the things that you would repeat in every component inside a function.

Comment: @Bergi Honestly, I've never done a custom hook, could you show me? I apologize for the importunity

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as advised in the comments using hook, it works fine, maybe it will be useful to someone. Custom hook is really convenient

```
export const useModal = () => {
    const [play, setPlay] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setPlay(!play)
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setPlay(false)
        setPlay(!play)
    };
    return {
        play, handleOpen, handleClose
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to pass down values and/or functions from a parent to two or more children, I think it's better to just have the values and functions in the parent

Parent :

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const [play, setPlay] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const handleOpen = () => {
        setPlay(prev => !prev)
    };
   
    const handleClose = () => {
        setPlay(false)
        setPlay(!play)
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ModalMenu handleOpen={handleOpen} handleClose={handleClose} play={play}/>

            <MainSlider  <ModalMenu handleOpen={handleOpen} handleClose={handleClose} play={play}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

if you want to pass an interface to the props in the children for typescript your interface will look something like this

```
interface iProps {
 play : boolean;
 handleOpen : () => void;
 handleClose : () => void;
}
```

```
export const ModalMenu: FC = (props):iProps => {
// you can easily access all you want
const {handleClose, handleOpen, play} = props

    return
}
```

```
export const Slider: FC= (props): iProps => {
const {handleClose, handleOpen, play} = props
    return (
        <>
            <Image onClick={handleOpen}/>
        </>
```

Comment: This is the problem that I have already done exactly as you described, but I decided to redo it, because in this case I will have to go to every page in Next.js add this logic =(

Comment: oh, now I understand..

Comment: Perhaps there is another way?